# Using Telnet in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, telnet

We are currently running several Projects on several Servers. For our workflow we installed Telnet to communicate with theses servers. More than this, we run the Build/Make mechanism (own development php) on theses servers.

Now we like to introduce a CI mechanism to this. Therefore we installed a central Jenkins application, from which we like to trigger all these builds. Our standard way is to open a telnet connection an trigger the build command on shell. Now we like to adopt this mechanism and bring it to Jenkins.

Is there a possibility to open a Telnet connection via Jenkins?

Installing a slave Jenkins on the remote Servers is a not as much preferred option, because we don't like to install more Software on the server as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is posible, you can use pipeline to include groovy program that use telnet commands, it could be one posibility another you can use ssh commands in a free style job.